# Swift - Proper usage of AnyObject

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, ios8

I am new to `swift`. I am using `storyboard` and according to logged in information, I am changing the `UIViewController` to load. Below is the snippet.

```
class func viewControllerWithName(name: String) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let storyboard = mainStoryboard()
        let viewController: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name)
        return viewController as? UIViewController
    }

func setUpController {
        let viewController: AnyObject!
        if self.user() == "admin" {
            viewController:AdminViewController = self.viewControllerWithName("admin") !as! AdminViewController
        } else {
            viewController:UserViewController = self.viewControllerWithName("user") !as! UserViewController
        }
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        viewController.view.frame = container.frame
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```

I tried many ways, but, I am unable to typecast `viewController`. I get error, saying

```
Cannot invoke 'addChildViewController' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject!)'
```

What is the right format to achieve this?

Comment: try change `let viewController: AnyObject!` to `let viewController: UIViewController!`

Comment: Didn't work. It gives me error in the 3rd line of `setUpController()`, which says, Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'` suggesting me to add ';' between `viewController';':AdminViewController`. Same for 5th line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you declare it as `AnyObject` when you know its going to be a view controller? declare it as  `UIViewController` and the error you've mentioned should go away.

You don't need to do `viewController:AdminViewController` in the if-else section. You are anyways force typecasting the output of `viewControllerWithName` method.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are indicating that viewController is AnyObject type:

```
let viewController: AnyObject!
```

To pass a UIVIewController to addChildViewController you can try something like:

```
let viewController = self.viewControllerWithName("admin") as! AdminViewController

self.addChildViewController(viewController)
```

In swift you cant change a let or var type at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Update your code and change AnyObject to UIViewController:

```
class func viewControllerWithName(name: String) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let storyboard = mainStoryboard()
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name) as? UIViewController
        return viewController 
    }

func setUpController {
        let viewController: UIViewController!
        if self.user() == "admin" {
            viewController = self.viewControllerWithName("admin")!
        } else {
            viewController = self.viewControllerWithName("user")! 
        }
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        viewController.view.frame = container.frame
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```